# "Switch mode" and "switching" - are they the same?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I live in the UK and have purchased an american FPGA (circuit board) that comes with a US plug.  I have found a [US-to-UK power adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Masterplug-Travel-TAVUK-MP-Visitor-Adaptor/dp/B000SWE2AY/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1515858246&sr=8-3&keywords=us%20to%20uk%20plug%20adapter); one of the comments about it says

*"...only use it with US items that are switch mode (things like laptop computers and phone chargers). You must not just plug in a US item that needs 110V - 120V for that you would need a Voltage Transformer as this adapter will not convert Voltage."*

Now, on the plug for my FPGA is written

**LTE Switching AC/DC power adapter**

**I/P: AC 100-240V 50/60H**

**O/P: DC 7.5V 0.2A**

Will the adapter I linked to work safely with this FPGA plug?

PS I'm sorry if I have asked this in the wrong area, but I felt this area would be frequented by people who are most likely to be able to help.

PPS I know the plug says "switching" but I'm not sure if this is the same as "switch mode", and would rather hear the facts from someone on here.

PPS I have done lots of google research prior to asking this but cannot find anything that suggests "switch mode" means "switching", so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How bizarre...

Anyway, since the adapter is just a mechanical outlet converter and your FPGA takes...

I/P: AC 100-240V 50/60H

Which includes your line supply in the UK of 230(240)/50Hz then you are good to go.

PS: And yes switch-mode and switching power supply is generally interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks Trevor.  Can I ask, what is bizarre?

Comment: Also, the quote I posted states "this adapter will not convert Voltage" but you say "adapter is just a mechanical outlet converter" - you are sure that that adapter I linked to will work fine with the FPGA?

Comment: @Wad The wording of that warning, typical though.

Comment: @Wad the adapter just changes the mechanical pins for a UK plug into the mechanical socket needed for a US plug. There is no transformer or electronics inside.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll purchase that adapter having put total faith in your answer Trevor!  Thanks!

Comment: @Wad, what the FPGA adapter says it needs is the key here. I assume it is a power brick, hence the need for an adapter. If it's just a lead with a US 2 (or 3) prong plug on the end, you could just cut it off and replace it with a standard UK plug. (Colour codes are different though)